# Laravel 5.3 com Ajax

Tags: ajax, json, post, request, route

Prezados peço a ajuda de vocês para me auxiliar a resolver um problema de Ajax com Laravel 5.3

Estou enfrentando problemas com Internal Server Error 500, e  procurando informações a respeito, pode ser problema de rotas ou de csrf_token(), porém já fiz as alterações e simplesmente não resolve. Onde é que posso estar errando? O sistema sequer chega no método no Controller.

Abaixo coloco as informações do projeto para tentar explicar a lógica e onde é que pode estar acontecendo.

Esse código é para carregar automaticamente o CEP nos campos.

A definição do campo CEP da página que contém o código Ajax é:

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'alunos.store','method'=>'POST']) !!}
<div class="col-md-2">
    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('CEP') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="text" name="cep" id="cep" class="form-control" placeholder="CEP somente números" value="{{old('CEP')}}" required="required"/>
   </div>
   @if ($errors->has('CEP'))
       <span class="help-block">
           <strong class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('CEP') }}</strong>
       </span>
   @endif
</div>
<div class="panel panel-footer">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check"> <b style="font-family: Arial">Salvar</b></i></button>
     <a href="{{ route('alunos.index')}}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i><b style="font-family: Arial"> Cancelar</b></button></a>
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Tenho um plane.blade.php que é carregado por todas as páginas. O seu conteúdo é:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Nova Escola</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport"/>
    <meta content="" name="description"/>
    <meta content="" name="author"/>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("assets/stylesheets/styles.css") }}" />
    <script src="{{asset('js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js')}}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    @yield('body')
    <script src="{{ asset("assets/scripts/frontend.js") }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
@yield('scripts')
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
</script>
```

A página que faz a requisição Ajax tem o seguinte código:

```
@section('scripts')
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        /* Executa a requisição quando o campo CEP perder o foco */
        $('#cep').blur(function(){
            /* Configura a requisição AJAX */
            $.ajax({
                url :'/cep', /* URL que será chamada */
                type : 'POST', /* Tipo da requisição */
                data: 'cep=' + $('#cep').val(), /* dado que será enviado via POST */
                dataType: 'json', /* Tipo de transmissão */
                success: function(data){
                    if(data.sucesso == 1){
                        $('#rua').val(data.rua);
                        $('#bairro').val(data.bairro);
                        $('#cidade').val(data.cidade);
                        $('#estado').val(data.estado);
                        $('#numero').focus();
                    }
                    else{
                        alert('retornou <> 1');
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
            })
        });
</script>
@stop
```

No web.php (Rota) eu defini desta forma:

```
Route::post('/cep', 'alunosController@cep');
```

No Controller eu montei dessa forma para recuperar a informação e retornar os dados de coleta de CEP.

```
public function cep(Request $request){
        $cep = $request; // $_POST['cep'];
        $reg = simplexml_load_file("http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=".$cep);
        $dados['sucesso'] = (string) $reg->resultado;
        $dados['rua']     = (string) $reg->tipo_logradouro.' '.$reg->logradouro;
        $dados['bairro']  = (string) $reg->bairro;
        $dados['cidade']  = (string) $reg->cidade;
        $dados['estado']  = (string) $reg->uf;

        return Response::json($cep);
    }
```

Comment: retire `return false;` dentro do `blur` ... e teste

Comment: Virgilio, fiz o que sugeriu, mas não adiantou. continua dando [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (cep, line 0) - http://localhost:8000/cep

Comment: qual é o erro que ele dá no javascript? tem como colocar a imagem, aperte F12 e verique o retorno do erro por favor?

Comment: chrome-extension://ahbkhnpmoamidjgbneafjipbmdfpefad/injectees/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
frontend.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null(…)
Launcher.js:3 *** *** *** request_settings
2Launcher.js:20 launching FocusManager.parse_for_input on DOM mutation event  - 2Launcher.js:20 launching FocusManager.parse_for_input on DOM mutation event
http://localhost:8000/cep Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: 132Launcher.js:20 launching FocusManager.parse_for_input on DOM mutation even - Virgílio é isso que aparece no console

Comment: Não consegui colar, estou usando Mac OS Sierra com Safari, porém o erro da no Safari e no Chrome e Opera

Comment: só com esses erros fica complicado com certeza, mas, parece rota que etá errada!

Comment: Tem alguma idéia de como montar? Eu já revi essa rota uma série de vezes e parece estar ok.

Comment: Quando no console eu coloco console.log(CSRF_TOKEN ) o mesmo retorna com a seguinte informação: VM286:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: CSRF_TOKEN is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53401/discussion-between-virgilio-novic-and-ricardo-facincani).

Comment: talvez existem coisas que além do formulário montado também estão erradas, sem ver fica complicado... é um erro pontual

Comment: Virgílio, acessei o chat mas acho que não estou habilitado para responder

Comment: verdade não deve ter permissão ainda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virgílio, consegui resolver. Você deu o caminho e fui procurando o problema.

O que estava acontecendo, era uma interferência / localização da section dentro do Blade master com o blade que estava o form / javascript. Também passei a usar o seu exemplo de Ajax, depois eu vou testar o que eu tinha feito para verificar se também poderia causar algum problema.

mas a resposta é que consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

No blade master, coloquei o meta tag e o handler de configuração do Ajax, no Blade intermediário, dentro do área do Body criei uma section com o nome @section('script') e no form que usei antes do @stop abri a section('script') e coloquei o Ajax e ai passou a funcionar.

Depois eu posto o código para melhor exemplificar como ficou.

Mas desde já gostaria de agradecer muito a sua contribuição. Valeu!

Comment: Ok @Ricardo ....

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi, desenvolver um *exemplo mínimo*, para que faça a comparação com o seu código, tinha alguns erros de codificação (*código faltando*).

***Exemplo minimo:***

***Html*** - `postcep.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            Cep: <input type="text" id="cep" name="cep" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Rua: <input type="text" id="rua" name="rua" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Bairro: <input type="text" id="bairro" name="bairro" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Cidade: <input type="text" id="cidade" name="cidade" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Estado: <input type="text" id="estado" name="estado" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#cep").on('blur', function()
           {
               value = $(this).val();
               if (value.length < 8)
               {
                   alert("Digite o cep");
                   return;
               }
               $.post("/post/cep", {cep:value}, function(data)
               {
                   $("#rua").val('');
                   $("#bairro").val('');
                   $("#cidade").val('');
                   $("#estado").val('');
                    if (data.sucesso != "0")
                    {
                        $("#rua").val(data.rua);
                        $("#bairro").val(data.bairro);
                        $("#cidade").val(data.cidade);
                        $("#estado").val(data.estado);
                    }
               }, 'json');
           });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

***Controller***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostCepController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('postcep');
    }

    public function cep(Request $request)
    {
        $cep = $request->input('cep');
        $url = "http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php?formato=xml&cep=".$cep;
        $reg = simplexml_load_file($url);
        $dados['sucesso'] = (string) $reg->resultado;
        $dados['rua']     = (string) $reg->tipo_logradouro.' '.$reg->logradouro;
        $dados['bairro']  = (string) $reg->bairro;
        $dados['cidade']  = (string) $reg->cidade;
        $dados['estado']  = (string) $reg->uf;
        return $dados;
    }
}
```

***Rotas***

```
Route::get('/post', 'PostCepController@index');
Route::post('/post/cep', 'PostCepController@cep');
```

<sup>***Observação:*** Para tirar todas as duvidas pode utilizar esse código como experimento, copiando e colando as configurações no seu projeto e testando.</sup>